# Dormant company, never paid taxes, never traded in UK - should I have notified the HMRC?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, corporation

I opened a LTD company for a startup, in order to reserve the company name, back in 2013. I sat down with a freelance accounting (whom I am not in touch with)to set the company up. He informed me that I would not need to do anything until the company started trading, which it never did. A company bank account was never set up.

I never received any mail from the HMRC at the registered address and I never informed the HMRC of anything, but I have been filing the relevant documentation using the Companies House filing website every year (bar last).

I now want to dissolve the company as last year I forgot to file the accounts and I don't really want the hassle going forward.

Am I ok to simply file a DS01 form and submit in writing the HMRC that the company is being dissolved?

I can't help but feel that I was a little naive in setting up the company and might get a shock when I do let them know?

Comment: A side note: "I opened a LTD company for a startup, **in order to reserve the company name**" - I would check with a lawyer to confirm that the name was actually "reserved". My understanding of the subject as a non-lawyer is that the name of your corporation might be almost meaningless. You might want to copyright it. Again I am not a lawyer but I also believe that something like this isn't perfect - if someone had a similar name later, they might be able to use it, if they weren't picking the name to benefit from your pre-existing brand. Talk to a lawyer if you still want the name "reserved".

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon The UK has a central registry ("Companies House") so probably it is reserved.

Comment: To clarify, 'reserve the name', meaning setting up a dormant company :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I had thought "reserve the name" meant to protect it from competitors / for branding purposes. My non-legal understanding in Canada is that coincidental name similarities are not necessarily protected by copyright / incorporation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to [register for corporation tax](https://www.gov.uk/limited-company-formation/set-up-your-company-for-corporation-tax) until you start doing business:

> After you’ve registered your company with Companies House, you’ll need to register it for Corporation Tax. You’ll need to do this within 3 months of starting to do business.

Since you haven't needed to do that yet, there also shouldn't be any need to tell HMRC you've stopped trading. So it should just be a question of telling Companies House - I guess it's possible they'll first want you to provide the missing accounts.